# CKEditor - dragover event

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, ckeditor

In the documentation for the Clipboard plugin, http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_clipboard, it is said that the editor listens to the dragover event but CKEDITOR.editor.dragover is not available.

How can I listen to the dragover event in the editor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CKEditor listen on the `dragover` event to prevent page reloading on drop and show user that he can not drop on some elements (toolbar, dialogs, etc.). It does not fire `editor#dragover`.

If you want to listen on this event you can attach your listen to the native object. Note that this object will be different on different browsers and editor types. It can be `document` or the editable element (`body`, `div`, etc.). To get proper element use [getDropTarget](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.plugins.clipboard-method-getDropTarget) method. Also that element will be removed when you switch the editor to the source mode and the new element will be created when you switch back to the editable mode, so use [attachListener](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editable-method-attachListener) method and [contentDom](http://docs.ckeditor.dev/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-contentDom) event instead of simple `on` method. The code will looks like this:

```
editor.on( 'contentDom', function() {
    var dropTarget = CKEDITOR.plugins.clipboard.getDropTarget( editor );
    editor.editable().attachListener( dropTarget, 'dragover', function( evt ) {
        // Your listener code here...
    } );
} );
```

If you thing that `editor#dragover` would be useful universally please create a ticket for it on http://dev.ckeditor.com/.